# How to completely copy all of the Toshiba laptop hard drive contents to another laptop?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, laptop, file-transfer

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop and I am buying another one, newer laptop and I have about 200GBs of stuff like games/apps on my hard drive. I could upload it online or do it with a USB drive but that will take a LONG time. Is it possible to transfer all data (possibly the OS too) on a different hard drive? Or just switch the hard drive of one laptop and stick it in another one?

Comment: are both hard drives sata?  Clonezilla if you have gigabit networking.  USB isn't bad if you have 3.0.  If sata and a spare desktop you can connect them both to the desktop and use Clonezilla.

Comment: I don't think they are. One is a laptop from 2009 and its pretty old.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend copying the OS (if old is Vista or XP) if the newer one came with, say, Win 8. More hassle than it's worth. If you have a Gigabit LAN then copy them over your network. CloneZilla is an imaging solution - for duplicating computers and shouldn't be used for anything else...

Comment: I have Windows 8 installed on both of them. Don't take me wrong, just because the older laptop is old, I kept it all clean and updated.